# Rotating Face Won't Stop Shaking

Tags: transforms, faces

I'm trying to rotate an object's face and keep having the problem where it will not stop shaking, even if the mouse is moving.

[Here's a giphy link to show what I'm talking about.](https://media.giphy.com/media/mPuF5HGnejSIo/giphy.gif)

Edit: Here's the blend link. It's not the snap-on option. I don't think I'm using modifiers on the object, but Im pretty new to this and could be wrong.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information on how you set up your scene, what kind of modifiers/constraints you are using. Consider uploading your scene so that it can be examined. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then include the resulting link as part of the text on your question.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea is than you have "Snap tool" ON. Check Magnet icon (in horshoe shape) on 3D Viwe bottom bar. Next to "Proportional editing". Keyshort is "Shif+Tab". Can be easily switched accidentally.

If this don't help you, consider uploading your .blend. Because we can only guess now.

Answer (score 0):

I was holding down the <kbd>X</kbd> key trying to get it to rotate along the X axis, but just realized I only need to press it once.